# what is the issue with my dictionary map in matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary

I wrote this code in matlab to take an image and convert it into a vector of integers these numbers I put it in dictionary map the key value I want it to be a string of the numbers from 0 to 255. Therefore, I convert the number to a string and put it as a key to the dictionary why I have these two errors below and how to fix it please

```
[filename pathname] = uigetfile({'*.tiff';'*.bmp'},'File Selector');

image=strcat(pathname,filename);
pic=imread(image);
Imgvector=pic(:);
c=256;

for j=0:255
    d=int2str(j);
    DictionaryMap(d)=j;
end

keyset=keys(DictionaryMap);
disp(keyset);
ws=Imgvector(1);

for i=2:length(Imgvector)
    w=Imgvector(i);
    w=int2str(w);
    ws=strcat(ws,w);
    tf=iskey(DictionaryMap,ws);
    if tf==1
    elseif tf==0
        c=c+1;
        ms=ws;
        DictionaryMap(ms)=c;
        ws=str(2:end);
    end
end
```

and I got these two errors:

> Undefined function or method 'keys' for input arguments of type 'double'.

in this line:

```
keyset=keys(DictionaryMap);
```

> Undefined function or method 'iskey' for input arguments of type 'double'.

in this line

```
tf=iskey(DictionaryMap,ws);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to inizialize 'DictionaryMap' as a containers like here http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.iskey.html :

```
months =   {'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'};
rainfall = [327.2, 368.2, 197.6, 178.4];
mapObj = containers.Map(months,rainfall);
```

you can modify

```
for j=0:255
    d=int2str(j);
    DictionaryMap(d)=j;
end
```

with the following code:

```
d = cell(c, 1);
x = [0:255];
for j=1:c
    d{j}=int2str(x(j));
end
DictionaryMap = containers.Map(d,x);
```

after that if you address the container with a string you can obtain the following results:
b=DictionaryMap('255') --> b = 255 and b=DictionaryMap('0') --> b = 0